# Do fixtures defined within a Nose test class get called between functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, fixtures, nose

Suppose I have a test class:

```
class testFoo():

    def bar():
      #assert stuff

    def baz():
      #assert stuff

    def setUp():
      config = {"stuff": "morestuff"}

    def tearDown():
      cleanup()
```

Are the fixtures(setUp and tearDown) supposed to be called between function calls (bar and baz)? Or does setUp only get called when the test class gets instantiated? Ideally, the fixtures would be called between function calls.

I read the documentation on this and it wasn't clear enough to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setUp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) and [`tearDown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) methods are called right before and after every test method.

If you need something to be called once before any of the test methods in the test case class are executed - define [`setUpClass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) class method, if once after all the methods were executed - define [`tearDownClass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass) class method.